# Ignorar carpetas en appspec.yml

Tags: git, github, aws

Saludos, tengo un problema de sincronizacion estre AWS y GIT, tengo un repositorio de fotos en un wordpress pero estas fotos no estan en el repositorio(Son casi 4 GB) el tema es cada vez que hago un commit me elimina la carpeta con las fotos.

Lo quiero es sincronizar el directorio completo del wordpress excepto la carpeta wp-content/uploads ignorarlo de algun modo y que no lo elimine.

Aca el contenido del archivo appspec.yml, que regla existe para que esta sincronizacion omita carpetas algo tipo "uploads/*"  he leido en la doc de amazon pero es confusa.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/change_permissions.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

Comment: ¿Y si usas `.gitignore`?

Comment: El git ignore me funciona no sincroniza la carpeta uploads, pero el tema es mas arriba aun. Es entre AWS y GIT, porque no solo es que no lo ignora es que elimina el directorio upload completo (Asumo que al sincronizar como no esta en git pues lo elimina de AWS), estoy leyendo aun mas a ver. Mi git ignore tiene esta regla /wp-content/uploads/*

Comment: No entiendo _cada vez que hago un commit me elimina la carpeta_. Es decir, ¿cada vez que haces `git push` desde local a AWS, en AWS se pierde la carpeta con las fotos? Haz una prueba, añade un fichero en `wp-content/uploads/` y mira si aparece al hacer `git status`. Así comprobarás si el fichero `.gitignore` está configurado correctamente.

Comment: Te comento la arquitectura:  [AWS]  <---Aquí se sincroniza automáticamente (Es en este proceso donde se elimina la el directorio)----> [GIT]<----Mi gitignore tiene la regla para excluir el directorio mencionado---->[LOCAL]